# SQL How can I count the number of meetings for each client?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables Meeting and client. I have two foreign keys in the meeting table id_client1 and id_client2. How can I count the number of meetings that took place between clients?

I have such a query

```
SELECT client.id_client, count(meet.id_client1)count_meeting
FROM meet JOIN client ON meet.id_client1=client.id_client
GROUP BY  client.id_client;
```

But this query only count meeting client1. What can I do to count the meetings for both clients?

I would like such a result

```
id_client       count_meeting
  1                   3
  2                   1
  3                   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want a union of the sets of clients:

```
SELECT id_client, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT id_client1 AS id_client FROM meet
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id_client2 AS id_client FROM meet
) participants
GROUP BY id_client
ORDER BY id_client;
```

And if you want to include clients that didn't participate in any meeting:

```
SELECT c.id_client, COUNT(p.id_client)
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id_client1 AS id_client FROM meet
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id_client2 AS id_client FROM meet
) p ON p.id_client = c.id_client
GROUP BY c.id_client
ORDER BY c.id_client;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how can i get the clients who had an meet on their birthday?

Comment: By comparing client ID and date, I guess. I'd probably use an `IN` clause for that. Something like `select * from client where (id_client, birthdate) in (select id_client, meetdate from meet);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a lateral join for this:

```
SELECT mc.id_client, COUNT(*) as count_meeting
FROM meet m CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT m.id_client_1 as id_client FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT m.id_client_2 FROM DUAL
     ) mc
GROUP BY mc.id_client;
```

The advantage of a lateral join is that it only scans the table once.  Another potentially fast method would use a subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select count(*)
        from meet m
        where c.id_client in (m.id_client_1, m.id_client_2)
       ) as count_meeting
from clients c;
```

Oracle has a good optimizer.  It should be able to use two indexes for this:  `meet(id_client_1)` and `meet(id_client_2)`.  If the optimizer misses this, you can split the logic into two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Without the tables I can't test this (also I don't have oracle) but hopefully this gives you some ideas atleast.

```
WITH clientone AS (
    SELECT id_client1, COUNT(id_client1) AS meetings1
    FROM meet
    GROUP BY id_client1),
clienttwo AS (
    SELECT id_client2, COUNT(id_client2) AS meetings2
    FROM meet
    GROUP BY id_client2)
SELECT id_client1, id_client2, (meetings1 + meetings2) AS meetings
FROM clientone OUTER JOIN clienttwo
ON id_client1 = id_client2;
```